# Methods queuing

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to figure out how to make the first method wait until the second method finish. I want to make a move animation of img1 and when this animation is done to make a animation of img2.

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
private ImageView img1;

@FXML
private ImageView img2;

public void initialize(){
    moveimg(img1);
    moveimg2(img2);
}

public void moveimg(ImageView i){
    TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
    transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
    transition.setToX(502);
    transition.setToY(238);
    transition.setAutoReverse(false);
    transition.setNode(img1);
    transition.play();

}

public void moveimg2(ImageView i){
    TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
    transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
    transition.setToX(22);
    transition.setToY(205);
    transition.setAutoReverse(false);
    transition.setNode(img2);
    transition.play();
}
```

Right now both images are moving in the same time. I think it might be something about threads but I don't know how to use them in right way.

Comment: you need to use `setOnFinished` method to start 2nd animation after 1st one is done

Comment: Or put both transitions into a `SequentialTransition`, and play the `SequentialTransition`.